# How to darken main content/canvas of site when side menu appears?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, jasny-bootstrap

I am currently using Bootstrap 3, specifically the Jasny Off Canvas Reveal Menu template, see here:

https://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/

All is working great but what I would like to achieve and unsure how to do as I'm not sure what click event is being fired when clicking on the hamburger menu icon to reveal the side menu but basically, I want to achieve the result here at this site, when the menu icon is pressed on the above Jasny example reveal, i.e.:

http://material-ui.com/#/

Here on the Material-UI site, the main content/canvas to the right of the menu is darkened when the menu is revealed and then returned back to it's original state when the side menu disappears.

I would like to get this going for the jasny off canvas reveal example menu click. The main thing though is, it needs to work on IE8 browser.

Comment: You can use `show.bs.offcanvas` and `hide.bs.offcanvas` events. [See docs](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas)

Comment: @anpsmn - using hide.bs.offcanvas event, in javascript, how could I attach this event to the keyboard ESC key?

Comment: You can write custom script for esc key and call  `$('.navmenu').offcanvas('hide')` which automatically will call hide event

Comment: How do I capture these show.bs.offcanvas and hide.bs.offcanvas events using jQuery?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/3mexbtgc/) for the events. I have added an overlay which is toggled depending on class `sliding`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @anpsmn - thanks for the fiddle - do you know if this will work in IE8 browser?

Comment: CSS3 transitions won't work in IE8. You can detect IE lower versions and use `fadeIn and fadeOut` like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/3mexbtgc/2/)

Comment: Will try this out tomorrow and let you know. Hopefully there are no issues with Firefox as I am attempting to make this work across all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add this CSS:

```
.canvas-slid:after,
.canvas-sliding:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    background: url(./alpha.png);
}
```

Since IE<=8 doesnt support rgba() you could use a 1x1px 50%alpha-PNG as BGimage[1](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/).

Comment: since I am on IE8, taking your rgba background-color, what would the MS-Filter values be, i.e. for -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#550000FF, endColorstr=#550000FF)"; ?

Comment: i dont know. Since FF/2=7F i guess its 7F000000

Comment: Your solution works a treat for non IE8 browsers but cannot seem to get it to work for IE8 though. Looked at and tried what Lea Verou suggested but to no avail. Any ideas?